# Update data in xampp database

Tags: php, android, xampp, android-networking

I have to update my database in correspondance to email.I am using Android Networking to update data in my database but it only is giving me server timeout. This is my PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{    
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databaseName = "truck_loader";

$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

$query = "UPDATE `users` SET 
`name`='".$name."',`address`='".$address."',`mobile`= $mobile WHERE `email` 
= $email";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if(mysqli_query($connect,$query))
{
$response['success'] = '1';
 $response['message']='Updated successfully';
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
else    
{
    $response['success'] = '0';
    $response['message']='Updation failed';
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

mysqli_close($connect);

}
?>
```

This my code in android:

```
 private void updateProfile() {
    HashMap<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name",name.getText().toString());
    params.put("email",email.getText().toString());
    params.put("mobile",mobile.getText().toString());
    params.put("address",address.getText().toString());
    AndroidNetworking.post("update.php").addBodyParameter(params).setTag("Profile").setPriority(Priority.LOW).build().getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                if(response.getString("success").equals("1")) {
                    Toast.makeText(FragProfile.this, response.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(FragProfile.this, response.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ANError anError) {
            Toast.makeText(FragProfile.this, "Server timeout please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

There is no exception shown the code so i am confused on what the error could be. 
EDIT: I am making this for the profile activity in my internship project, therefore, I have not used session in it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

}
```

The reason is that you aren't sending the key `update` from Android to php.

Also please do use prepared statements to prevent sql injection